# Installing conda package from local path works, but not from anaconda.org

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, conda-build

I've built a package through `conda-build`. When I'm installing it through `conda install --use-local PACKAGENAME` it works perfectly. Afterwards, I'm uploading the package to anaconda.org through `anaconda upload PATH`. But when I'm trying to install the package from anaconda.org, it doesn't work. It installs without errors, but I can't import the package and I can't use the related CLI. What could be the reason for this?

Here is my meta.yaml, which I used to built the package:

```
{% set name = "packagename" %}
{% set version = "1.0.0" %}

package:
  name: "{{ name|lower }}"
  version: "{{ version }}"

source:
  url: "https://test.pypi.io/packages/source/{{ name[0] }}/{{ name }}/{{ name }}-{{ version }}.tar.gz"
  sha256: 32d605e578c30c4XXXXXXXX0f81030dd9396588752800a5e4f796f0

build:
  number: 0
  script: "{{ PYTHON }} -m pip install ."

requirements:
  host:
    - pip
    - python
    - requests >=2.5.0
  run:
    - python
    - requests >=2.5.0

test:
  imports:
    - packagename

about:
  home: "https://gitlab.com/lab/data-services/packagename"
  license: MIT
  license_family: MIT
  license_file: 
  summary: "A cool data access client"
  doc_url: 
  dev_url:
```

And here my setup.py:

```
import os
from setuptools import setup

about = {}
with open(os.path.join("PACKAGENAME", "__version__.py")) as f:
    exec(f.read(), about)

with open("README.md", mode="r") as file:
    readme = file.read()

setup(
    name=about["__title__"],
    version=about["__version__"],
    description=about["__description__"],
    long_description=readme,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    author=about["__author__"],
    author_email=about["__author_email__"],
    url=about["__url__"],
    license=about["__license__"],
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
        "Intended Audience :: Developers",
        "Programming Language :: Python",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.9",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: CPython",
        "Programming Language :: Python :: Implementation :: PyPy",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    packages=["PACKAGENAME"],
    package_data={"PACKAGENAME": ["endpoints.ini"]},
    python_requires=">=3.7",
    install_requires=["requests>=2.5.0"],
    extras_require={
        "test": ["mypy", "pytest", "pytest-cov", "responses", "types-requests", "types-setuptools"]
    },
    scripts=[os.path.join("bin", "PACKAGENAME")],
)
```

Comment: Are you confident local test is really testing the local package? E.g., you might be leaking in a user-level install of the package rather than loading the Conda one. Does your local one still load the module if you launch with `python -s`? That is, I'm raising the possibility that the build is altogether broken, and Anaconda Cloud part may not be relevant.

Comment: @merv Thanks for this hint. I tried to launch the module with `python -s` and... it works! So, it seems to be a problem with Anaconda Cloud, right? Or is there anything else to test the build?

Comment: What does `conda list PACKAGENAME` show under the `channel` section? Should say `local` and not `pypi`. For the one installing from Anaconda Cloud, does your install command look like `conda install -c USERCHANNEL PACKAGENAME`, or are you doing something else?

Comment: Yes, it says `local` as it should. No, I don't do anything else. That's why I'm so confused on this.